# Fire OnClick after OnClientClick AJAX has finished

Tags: asp.net, ajax, onclick, jsonp, onclientclick

I'm using ASP.Net and need to call a server side function after the JavaScript function has **completely finished**.

The problem is that it's executing the server code before the client code is finished and my hidden value is empty.  AJAX call is across domains so using **async: false** doesn't seem to work.

I've added the basic code below to explain a bit better.

HTML

```
<input id="hdnToken" type="hidden" name="hdntoken" value="" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return getToken();" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="Server"></asp:Button>
```

JavaScript

```
function getToken() {
    $.ajax({
        async: false, // Ignored across domains
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: OnSuccess,
        error: OnError
    });

    function OnSuccess(response) {
        $('#hdnToken').val(response);
        return true;
    }

    function OnError(response) {
        console.log(response);
        return false;
    }
};
```

ASP.Net Server side code

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hidden = Request.Form["hdnToken"];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple trick would be to place a LinkButton on the page with no text but with an OnClick event.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then you can simulate the PostBack from that link with the `UniqueID`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function simulateClick() {
        __doPostBack('<%= LinkButton1.UniqueID %>', '');
    }
</script>
```

Now when the `simulateClick()` is run, it wil trigger the `LinkButton1_Click` method in code behind.

By placing a dummy LinkButton you don't need to disable `enableEventValidation`